# EU4 production interface cut off

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Getting a strange bug that I can't find a fix for. The top of my production interface windows are getting cut off a little. The first line is just missing and the second like is cut in half. It doesn't just appear to be a graphic bug but also the button is just gone. Clicking the blank space has zero affect from the button that was there. As you can see in the screenshots.
I've played eu4 for ages and never had any problems. This started after 2 changes, one eldorado dlc downloaded and active. 2nd is I plugging my comp into my HD T.V. Which is 51" compared to my previous 25/27" monitor. I havn't had any problems elsewere in other games. The native resolution is 1024 x 768. That made words in eu4 a little annoying but not a problem when it came to playing really. The interface being cut off is the real issue as nothing I have tried has had any affect. Compatibility and drivers now triple checked. This is also the only problem I have found, the rest of the game and other interfaces are running fine. Can join multiplayer games etc so its not affected that either.
Checksum is not different to other players whos games are working fine. Iv reninstalled the game, verified files, triple checked every single driver but no affect.
Any random idea at this point would be appreciated as I'v never seen or heard of a problem like this.
(Sorry for how long the question is, I'm trying to be thorough)

http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198050515253/screenshot/527260585192167934

http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198050515253/screenshot/527260585192166489

More screenshots are there but cant post more. All from the main production interface window.

Comment: That is strange. Have you consider submitting a bug report on the paradox forums: https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?forums/euiv-bug-reports.813/ ?

Comment: Already did that @lorentzfactor . Only been up since tuesday but no reply yet.

Comment: The fact that it persists after you reinstall it would suggest it has something to do with information that was not deleted when you uninstalled it. The only place I can think of where that's the case is in your documents folder. I would be especial suspicious of your settings file. http://www.eu4wiki.com/Settings  Perhaps fiddling around with that will yield results?

Comment: Thank you so much! @lorentzfactor Never occured to me that the settings being in documents would keep regenning the same damn data. I deleted with it and kept changing the screen res and I finally found one that worked! EU4 really doesn't play well on certain screen res's it looks like. Now all I need to figure out is how to set your comment to answer lol

Comment: Glad to have help. I actually had a similar problem myself awhile back-hopefully now it won't cause quite as many users so much grieve.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it persists after you reinstall it would suggest it has something to do with information that was not deleted when you uninstalled it. The only place I can think of where that's the case is in your documents folder. I would be especial suspicious of your [settings file](http://eu4wiki.com/Settings).  Perhaps fiddling around with that will yield results?